# How to set image as a icon in radiofield?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, radio-button

I have a group of radio buttons. I am not able to set image as a icon in radiofield.
Here is my code :

```
items: [
{
    icon: 'img/rag123a.',
    name: 'rag',
    id: 'rag1',
    margin: '0 10 0 0'
}
]
```

Something like this I want :

[image]

Comment: I fixed your code. Did I fix it correctly. Please check.

Comment: Would you like to change the icon of the radio button like [this](http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.2.0/resources/ext-theme-classic/images/form/radio.gif)?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer - no, its not working.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer it's a valid one. I use same in button. And do you think it's a nonsense? Really??

Comment: It was, that's why I fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want to show the image in the label of the radiobutton?  if yes, one way to warp the image is to put it in the **boxLabel** as shown in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/NUPD2/

*the source of the icon was copied from https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/40737/bar_chart_icon#size=128 in this example*

```
{
            boxLabel: '<img src="url/to/image" width="20" height="20"/>',
            name: 'size',
            inputValue: 'l',
            id: 'radio2'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
      {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            columnWidth: 1,
            fieldLabel: 'Achat',
            items: [
            {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                name: 'typeAchat',
                boxLabel: '<img src="images/optique/glasses.png"/>',
                checked: true,
                inputValue: 'lunetteOptique'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'radiofield',
                name: 'typeAchat',
                boxLabel: '<img src="images/optique/JustGlasse.png"/>',
                inputValue: 'glasses'
            },
             ...
            ]
        },
```